# Heroku accessing environmental variable issues

Tags: python, heroku, environment-variables

I am trying to deploy a plotly dash app to Heroku, but I have API keys I need to hide. I can't seem to get it to deploy. It works locally when I use the subprocess library like below to make a method for pulling environment variables. However, when I try to access the app online the logs give me an unauthorized 401 error for the API I'm pulling from.

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE

def out(command):
    result = run(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=True)
    return result.stdout


key = out('heroku config:get key')
```

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just import `os` at the top and use `os.environ["key"]` to get the API Key (replacing `key` with whatever you called the environment variable).

Comment: When I try to do that I get KeyError 'key' because they're not in a .env file, but in Heroku's config vars.

Comment: Heroku's config vars are set as environment variables in Heroku applications. Are you sure the config var is named "key"?

Comment: Yes, but I did it through settings in Heroku is that the problem? or do I need the variable name to have quotes around it?

Comment: It should work fine no matter where the config vars are defined...

Comment: I don't know then it won't work for some reason.

Comment: do i need to initialize my keys in any way

Comment: Change it to `os.environ.get("KEY", "default_value")`. Locally when no env key is set it will take the `default_value`. On Heroku with the env var `$KEY` set it will take that env var.  
Alternatively make sure you are setting the env variables locally when executing the project.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Seth's answer, the top of my settings.py looks like this:

```
import environ
import os

env = environ.Env(
    DEBUG=(bool, False)
)

READ_DOT_ENV_FILE = env.bool('READ_DOT_ENV_FILE', default=False)
if READ_DOT_ENV_FILE:
    environ.Env.read_env()

DEBUG = env('DEBUG')
SECRET_KEY = env('SECRET_KEY')
```

and in `Heroku->settings->config vars` it looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfnmT.png)